React with MUI: How to build a footer
I have a footer at the bottom of my page, where I want the following:

Be all the way at the bottom after the content of the page
Be at the bottom of the screen if there's not enough content to fill the page
I am using React with Material UI


I've found some guides using the height of the footer as a buffer, but that requires hardcoding that height. (Such as where I got the picture: link.)
I've also found guides using flexbox, and while that seems easy enough, I can't get it to work within react. I've tried this example.
Code:
import type { Metadata } from "next";

import "./globals.css";

import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from "@mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { AppBar, Typography } from "@mui/material";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Footer example",
  description: "How can footers be hard?"
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: Readonly<{ children: React.ReactNode }>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
          <Box
            sx={{
              height: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column"
            }}
          >
            <AppBar sx={{ height: "80px" }} />
            <Box
              sx={{
                flexGrow: 1,
                flexShrink: 0,
                flexBasis: "auto"
              }}
            >
              {children}
            </Box>
            <Box
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: "lightblue",
                flexShrink: 0
              }}
            >
              <Typography>Example footer!</Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

To use height 100%, like you did on the first box, a absolute height needs to be set on its parent element. And to make sure that the footer is always on the bottom even when there is not much content, you can set a min-height to the main content e.g. min-height: 90vh.

So I just needed to replace the 100% by 100vh. Thank you so much! I knew there was something simple to be done, just couldn't find it. Thanks again!

Yes. But be careful by just setting it as height. Its better when you declare a minHeight instead, so the "max' is still unlimited.
